# Javascript / JQuery Contenteditable resize handles should set table column width parameter

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm looking for a solution primarily supported by Webkit browsers (Chrome / Edge / Safari) that allows table columns to change the actual width of these columns when the resize property is set in a contenteditable field. Now here's what I've done so far.

I've added the resize handles in the first row of the columns by adding the following CSS (.editortable is the class for the tables) :

```
.editortable tr:first-child td {
    padding: 4px;
    cursor:pointer;
    resize:both;
    border: 1px dotted #333;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

This shows the resize handles in the contenteditable field, allowing for rescaling the table columns. But what it doesn't do, is set the new width and height in the underlying HTML by adding a "width" and "height" attribute with the appropriate values. How can this be done in either vanilla javascript or JQuery?

Sorry for my English, it's not my native language. I hope you guys understand what I'm trying to accomplish here.

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <table class="editortable">
      <tr>
         <td>1</td><td>Just some text</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here's the fiddle; https://jsfiddle.net/7trwxoug/

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example of what's working at the moment

Comment: Edited the original message. The CSS and HTML is pretty straightforward as you can see. You can capture the changes you make in the contenteditable field, that's the easy part. But what is ignored is the changes you make in width and height when resizing the table cells. So what I'm looking for is a way to add the actual width and height of the individual cells, based on the resize values through the "width" and "height" paramters.

Here's the fiddle; https://jsfiddle.net/7trwxoug/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need MutationObserver, I added example code to watch the change of second `td`, you can watch any cell as you like, after watch whenever you resize a cell, the callback can get the latest widht/height, and you can set/log or other action according to widht/height and id you get

https://jsfiddle.net/46tamyzp/10/

[image]

Comment: One step closer to a solution, excellent, thanks! The only issue is that I can't give all the cells a separate ID.

Comment: @Léon you can query all td and pass each element insteadof id

Comment: And how does one do that?

Comment: @Léon https://jsfiddle.net/3rLb4ukm/1/

Comment: You sir, are awesome! Thanks, this is something I can most definitely work with. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I now have to see how I can make this code capture any resizing activities and ad the width and height values to the cell that has been resized.